# Yii comparing two attributes of different models

Tags: php, yii

In my web application  I need to compare attributes of two different models. I  have two models named "ProducerOffer" and "BookVegetable" . I need to compare the two individual attributes   . "booked_quantity" of "BookVegetable" table and "offered_qty" of "ProducerOffer" table . The condition should check if the "booked_quantity" is less than the "offered_quantity".
The code I wrote for my check condition

```
public function compareBookedQuantity($booked_quantity,$params){
    if(BookVegetable::model()->findByAttributes(array('booked_quantity'=>$booked_quantity ))> $this->offered_qty){

        $this->addError($attribute,'Please enter a quantity lesser than offered quantity');
      }
    }

public function rules()
{

array('offered_qty','compareBookedQuantity'),


 array(' vegetable_id, offered_qty, unit_cost, unit_delivery_cost', 'required'),
        array(' offered_qty, unit_cost, unit_delivery_cost, booking_status, booked_by, available_days', 'numerical'),
        array('user_id', 'length', 'max'=>11),
array('offered_qty','compareBookedQuantity'),


array('id,userName,user_id, vegetable_id, unit_cost,book_vegetable_id, unit_delivery_cost, offered_date,offered_quantity,available_quantity,booking_status, booked_by, available_days', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}
```

But the validation is not happening at all. How should I correct this error?

Answer (score 0):

$booked_quantity - is an Attribute - not attribute value. Your function must be:

```
public function compareBookedQuantity($booked_quantity,$params){
    $count = BookVegetable::model()->findByAttributes(array('booked_quantity'=>$this->$booked_quantity))->#field#;
    if ($count > $this->offered_qty)
        $this->addError($booked_quantity,'Please enter a quantity lesser than offered quantity');
}
```

Comment: BookVegetable::model()->findByAttributes(array('booked_quantity'=>$this->$booked_quantity)) will return an object not a scalar value. And how do you know that ProducerOffer model has booked_quantity attribute? Generally the question and the code provided by user2492854 are not clear.

Comment: no in my application "booked_quantity" belongs to    "BookVegetable" table. So I can't use $this variable . What should the "field" variable have? should I enter the value of that variable in the model? How can I refer to that pls help